# Directory Mapping & Action Mapping

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have two directories, both with the same contents for the purpose of debugging. One is titled `zxc` and the other is titled `welcome`. I am trying to get my action to use the `welcome` directory, using this code:

```
<action name="welcome">
    <result>/welcome/welcome.jsp</result>
</action>
```

When I use `<result>/zxc/welcome.jsp</result>` then the page is displayed successfully. When I use the above `<result>/welcome/welcome.jsp</result>` then I get `error 404 - resource not found`.

**EDIT 1:**

I also have this action, which will basically redirect to `welcome` when the url is left blank:

```
<action name="">
    <result type="redirect">welcome</result>
</action>
```

**EDIT 2:**

struts.xml configuration:

```
<package name="website" namespace="/" extends="struts-default, json-default">
   ...
</package>
```

Both of the above actions are situated inside of this package.

Comment: what exactly you want to do..?

Comment: sorry may be slow in understanding but still i am not sure what exact problem you are facing here.you can simple map this URL and on success which is default it will go to `welcome/welcome.jsp` :)

Comment: Do you want that the path appear in the URL like that: `example.org/welcome/welcome.jsp`?

Comment: that's strange.since i believe `welcome` is a directory which containing your welcome.jsp file

Comment: @ThreaT: not sure about the behavior,will check in once i have time as why its doing this, seems a bit interesting to me

Comment: @Quaternion: Please see **EDIT 2**. Are you saying that namespaces **alone** are responsible for specifying the directory?

Comment: I'm not but if you have the struts2-conventions-plugin in your class path that is also a possibility. What do you mean by folder? (There is the folder containing the view, there is the packages containing the actions and there is the namespace[which is more of a string that looks like a folder than a real folder structure])  Why not provide enough information to answer the question? Why not show the actual xml rather than what you think is important, the urls you are entering along with the desired and actual result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a namespace problem, the solution is:

```
<action name="">
    <result type="redirect">/welcome</result>
</action>
```

example:

if the URL is `http://hostname/${contextPath}/something/something`, then if you redirect to `welcome`, the URL will look like this `http://hostname/${contextPath}/something//welcome/welcome.jsp`, which refers to `404`, if you redirect to `/welcome`, it should be redirected to 'http://hostname/${contextPath}/welcome/welcome.jsp'.

`Important:` I am not sure, if you should write down `/welcome`, or use `<param name="namespace">/</param>`. I am using convention plugin. Just try it out.

Comment: Thanks. Although, that action works perfectly. Nothing about it needs to change except the `type` as mentioned above... The problem is with the other action: `<action name="welcome">
    <result>/welcome/welcome.jsp</result>
</action>`

Comment: hi, have you tried my solution. i know that the other action has problem, but i tried this by myself, and it should be right.